# CGAffineTransform to View center

Tags: swift, uiview, cgaffinetransform, cgpoint

I am using `self.logoImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 250)` to move my logo to the center of the screen when a button is clicked, however I would like to be sure it moves to the exact center of the screen on any device (`250` here does the trick on my iPhone 6 only).

How can I do? I failed trying CGPoint or maybe couldn't find the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a auto-layout constraints to make the image view's horizontal and vertical center the same as the view controller's content view center. (You might need to adjust for the status bar)

Comment: Actually I want the logo to move when a `Begin Button` is tapped. it was obvious to me but I forgot to include that in the question. The `Image View` is at the top of the view before clicking the button